# Do researchers receive no income from revenues arising from their published papers?

Tags: economics, scientific-papers

According to this article [*Meet the Robin Hood of Science*](http://bigthink.com/neurobonkers/a-pirate-bay-for-science) (about the creator of a website to bypass paper access restrictions and paywalls),

> Elbakyan made a point that will likely come as a shock to many outside
>   the academic community: **Researchers and universities don’t earn a
>   single penny from the fees charged by publishers** such as Elsevier
>   for accepting their work, while Elsevier has an annual income over a
>   billion U.S. dollars. Elbakyan explains: “I would also like to mention
>   that Elsevier is not a creator of these papers. All papers on their
>   website are written by researchers, and **researchers do not receive
>   money from what Elsevier collects**. That is very different from the
>   music or movie industry, where creators receive money from each copy
>   sold. ..."

(emphasis mine)

Is this assertion true, that researchers generally don't share the revenues arising from access to their papers?

Comment: Strictly speaking, the first bolded part is wrong. Elsevier and other publishers pay corporate taxes, a part of which goes into research grants, a part of which goes into the researchers' and universities' pockets.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

It's surprisingly hard to find a reference for this, as it is simply common knowledge among scientists. You don't get paid for publishing a paper in a scientific journal, sometimes you even have to pay yourself, e.g. in many open access journals.

I can show the negative, though. In the following graphic from the Nature article ["Open access: The true cost of science publishing"](http://www.nature.com/news/open-access-the-true-cost-of-science-publishing-1.12676) the costs of scientific publishing are detailed.

[image]

You'll notice that nowhere is any mention of paying the scientists that did the research. Even the scientists peer-reviewing the articles don't get paid at all.

> The biggest travesty, he says, is that the scientific community
>   carries out peer review — a major part of scholarly publishing — for
>   free, yet subscription-journal publishers charge billions of dollars
>   per year, all told, for scientists to read the final product

[Another article in the Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2012/apr/22/academic-publishing-monopoly-challenged) confirms this:

> But it's not just the exorbitant subscriptions that stink; it's the
>   intrinsic absurdity of what's involved in the academic publishing
>   racket. Most publishers, after all, have at least to pay for the
>   content they publish. But not Elsevier, Springer et al. Their content
>   is provided free by researchers, most of whose salaries are paid by
>   you and me.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35705/discussion-on-answer-by-mad-scientist-do-researchers-receive-no-income-from-reve).

Comment: Even without payment, I believe there is still an economic incentive: aren't academics rather crudely quantified (when it comes to grant-time) by the number of published papers with their names on? Not saying this is good or bad, it would just explain why they seem to be prepared to work for nothing.